# Android - Get last value from list

Tags: android, arrays, android-volley

I am facing very strange problem.
I have to send some data to sever using volley library in Json format. I'll get data from another API and forward it to server. Now problem is that every time I call function to create JSON it will get last value from list.

Here is code to convert jsonarray

```
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonBody;
JSONObject object;
```

Inside onclick of button I create jsonarray  - code below

```
btn_rec_invest_now.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.e(TAG, "Size of list : " + sipDetailses.size());

            jsonBody = new JSONArray();
            object = new JSONObject();

            for (int i = 0; i < sipDetailses.size(); i++) {

                String ID = sipDetailses.get(i).getId();
                String DATE = sipDetailses.get(i).getSip_date_include();
                String AMOUNT = sipDetailses.get(i).getMinimum_investment();
                String TENURE = "1";

                Log.e(TAG, "ID : " + ID);
                Log.e(TAG, "DATE : "
                        + sipDetailses.get(i).getSip_date_include());
                Log.e(TAG, "AMOUNT : "
                        + sipDetailses.get(i).getMinimum_investment());
                Log.e(TAG, "TENURE : " + i);
                Log.e(TAG, "USER ID : " + "1");
                Log.d(TAG, "=================");

                try {
                    object.put("sch_id", sipDetailses.get(i).getId());
                    object.put("date", DATE);
                    object.put("amount", AMOUNT);
                    object.put("tenure", TENURE);
                    object.put("user_id", "1");

                    jsonBody.put(object);



                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "EXCEPTION OCCRUDED: " + e.toString());
                }
            }
            try {
                mainObject.put("A", jsonBody);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("", "JSONBODY : " + mainObject.toString());

            sendDetails(mainObject);
        }
    });
```

The value I logged is coming correct but sch_id in mainObejct coming duplicate, here is json that was created

```
{
  "A": [
    {
      "sch_id": "738",
      "date": "1,7,15,25",
      "amount": "5000",
      "tenure": "1",
      "user_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "sch_id": "738",
      "date": "1,7,15,25",
      "amount": "5000",
      "tenure": "1",
      "user_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "sch_id": "738",
      "date": "1,7,15,25",
      "amount": "5000",
      "tenure": "1",
      "user_id": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here sch_id always comes 738 while - Log.e(TAG, "ID : " + ID); ID comes different like some time - 738, 607, 521 etc - That is coming correct.
Help me to get correct sch_id in array. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try this `jsonBody = mainObject.getJsonArray("A");` As per your json.

Comment: Could you specify what `sipDetailses` contains ?

Comment: sipDetailses is a getter-setter type class, that holds data comes from another api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are creating object for your JSONObject outside the loop.
Create instance for your object (object = new JSONObject();)
for inside for loop. like below

```
for (int i = 0; i < sipDetailses.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

    // do your operations

    jsonBody.put(object);
```

}